# Bad rightOperand type: got SObjectScriptRow

Tags: process-builder, sobject, invocable-method

I just want to know what is SObjectScriptRow! All I can find about it is [this question.](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Ag4MIAS)

I'm building an [invocable method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) to be used from a [process](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Process_Builder), where I have one input parameter: a list of an sObject type.

Here is the code:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Update fees' description='It takes a list of parent fees and updates the related child fees')
global static void ParentFeeUpdateChildFees(List<Parent_Fee__c> parentFees) {

    List<Child_Fee__c> childFees = [SELECT Parent_Fee__c, Fee_Percentage__c, Charge__c FROM Child_Fee__c WHERE Parent_Fee__c IN :parentFees];
    Map<Id,Parent_Fee__c> parentFeeMap = new Map<Id,Parent_Fee__c>(parentFees);

    Parent_Fee__c parentFee;
    for (Child_Fee__c childFee : childFees){                
        parentFee = parentFeeMap.get(childFee.Parent_Fee__c);
        childFee.Fee_Percentage__c = parentFee.Fee_Percentage__c;
        childFee.Charge__c = parentFee.Charge__c;
    }
    update childFees;
}
```

And I'm getting the following error

> FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR An Apex error occurred: System.UnexpectedException: Bad rightOperand type: got SObjectScriptRow: operator e dataType 1

So, I think the error is being thrown at the `:parentFees` meaning I can't query by the parameter because I'm actually getting a list of `SObjectScriptRow` instead of a list of `sObject`.

I can simply change the method to receive a list of Ids and this will work, but It will add an extra query to get the Parent Fees which I want to avoid.

I would appreciate any input in this, or maybe I'm mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: The clause `WHERE Parent_Fee__c IN :parentFees` is expecting a list of ids to be in `parentFees`. Since you have a list of sObjects, it's never going to work. However, if you extract the parentFee Id from the list of parentFees in a loop prior to the query, you can put it in a set and query that.

Comment: Hi @CasparHarmer, you can actually query by a list of sObjects. Just try the following `List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account limit 10];
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accounts];` and you'll see that you get a list of contacts. I know I have several workarounds to get this to work (like putting the ids in a set), but I just want to know what is SObjectScriptRow! and why am I getting that.

Comment: Hmm, interesting - I'm guessing that's because the sObjects get serialized into a form that fits the `IN` syntax, which makes the query work.

Comment: What happens if you replace `:parentFees` with `:parentIds` where that is defined as `new Map<Id, Parent_Fee__c>(parentFees).keySet()`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson that'd work just fine, but that's another workaround and wouldn't answer my question.

Comment: You have answered this question as well as it is possible to answer without insider knowledge. Basically, it represents an `SObject` that has been passed in through a `Process Builder` flow. While there are some people on this network with some such knowledge, your best course of action is to open a ticket with support.

Comment: I am receiving the same issue with my process builder which invokes a apex. Is there any workaround for this now ?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue and resolved by changing my method parameter from `List<SObject>` to `List<Id>`, worked like a charm